# __init__ : Inheriting __init__ parameter (dict) to another class's __init__ method?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, oop, inheritance

I am confused even after checking many questions asked in SO. I have 2 different class (2 different script) & I want to inherit super class's `__init__` method's parameters.

script1.py

```
class MainClass():
    def __init__(self,params):
        self.one=params['ONE']
        self.two=params['TWO']
        self.three=params['THREE']
        self.four=params['FOUR']
        self.five=params['FIVE']

     def a():
         #---------
         #somecode
         #Initializing other class's object to access it's method.
         s=SubClass()    #HERE I WANT TO PASS 'PARAMS' (WHICH IS A DICTIONARY)
         s.method1(....)
```

script2.py

```
class SubClass(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self,params):
         #Here I want all the parameters inside the 'param' in super class.
         #(one,two,three...., etc).
         #By checking some SO questions, I changed class SubClass() -->
         #class Subclass(SuperClass) & below line:
         MainClass.__init__(self,params) #But technically I don't have anything
                                         #in param in subclass.

     def method1():
         #some code...
```

Since sub class's param doesn't have anything, It gives me an error:

```
self.one=params['ONE']
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I am not getting:

1. How can I access all the parameters of super class to sub class in a simplest way? I don't want to pass individual arguments (like self.one, self.two..) to the sub class.
2. If I am calling third class inside `SubClass` -> `method1` --> Call 3rd class same as passing 'params'. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you want. Could you provide some code examples for how you want to initialize and interact with `SubClass`?

Comment: What's `SuperClass`?

Comment: `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): MainClass.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)`?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

**script1.py**

```
class MainClass():
    def __init__(self,params):
        # Save params for use by a
        self.params = params
        self.one=params['ONE']
        self.two=params['TWO']
        ...
        self.five=params['FIVE']

     def a():
         s=SubClass(self.params)
         s.method1(...)
```

**script2.py**

```
class SubClass(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self,params):
         MainClass.__init__(self,params)

     def method1():
         #some code...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any and all the non-keyword arguments from the subclass's `__init__()`to the superclass's like this:

```
class SubClass(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self, *params):
        MainClass.__init__(self, *params)
        ...
```

This same idea will work for other methods, too.